# Remove empty values from hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have recive such params from request

```
params[:search] = {"user_id_in"=>[""], "status_in"=>[""], "priority_in"=>["", "8"]}
```

I need to clear it, because metasearch gem works incorrect with it

```
params[:search] = {"priority_in"=>["8"]}
```

Comment: you want to get this from that params: params[:search] = {"priority_in"=>["8"]} ?

Comment: I want to remove all values wich equal to [""] or ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a solution with double select usage:

```
params[:search] = {"user_id_in"=>[""], "status_in"=>[""], "priority_in"=>["", "8"]}

params[:search].select! do |k, v|
  v.select! do |vv|
    !vv.empty?
  end
  v.length > 0
end
```

Comment: +1; more or less same as mine, although I'd use `!vv.empty?`.

Answer (score 2):

Functional approach (except, of course, for the last assign since you asked for a in-place update):

```
pairs = params[:search].map { |k, vs| [k, vs.reject(&:blank?)] }
params[:search] = Hash[pairs.select { |k, vs| vs.present? }]
```